# Send command to termux terminal from a button in android application

Tags: termux

I created an android app in which it has termux terminal inside, so basically it is termux but with more activities and menus etc, my problem is that i want to send commands to termux terminal activity from a button, remember termux is inside my app and it runs good, any ideas on how i can do this?